# Some code of reading .csv file crashed

Tags: c, dynamic

I tried make a code to read a csv file and change one value by getting line and column. In the first I read the file to check how many lines and cols up there, and than I create a dynamic 2D array- every line is the line on the file. actually make the file in 2D array. and than I will change the value of the chosen line and col and write the whole array back to the file. someone know why it's crashed? it's crashed in the first line of -

> bigArr[i][j]=(char)ch;

the function:

```
int changeValue(int line, int col, char str[],const char* path)
{
    FILE* csvFile = fopen(path, "r");
    char arr[VERY_BIG_MEMORY];
    int l = 0, c = 1;
    int i = 0,j=0;
    int ch = 0;
    if (!csvFile)
    {
        printf("Cant read the file\nPlease open a file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(csvFile);
        if (ch == ',')
        {
            c++;
        }
    } while (ch !='\n');
    fseek(csvFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(csvFile);
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            l++;
        }
    } while (ch!=EOF);
    char** bigArr = (char**)calloc(l*c,sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < l*c; i++)
    {
        bigArr[i] = (char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    }
    fseek(csvFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    do
    {

        ch = fgetc(csvFile);
        if (ch == ',')
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            bigArr[i][j]=(char)ch;
        }
    } while (ch != EOF);
}
```

Comment: delete `char arr[VERY_BIG_MEMORY];` because it's unused.

Comment: `char arr[VERY_BIG_MEMORY]`: probably don't want to allocate that on the stack! How big is very big? Could you be killing your stack? better to allocate on the heap using `malloc()` or (just read BLUPIXY's comment) as he says, remove it...

Comment: Do you have an error message to narrow down the cause?

Comment: Why don't you count rows and columns in the same loop? And don't use `c` for columns, use `columns_count` or something understandable, likewise for the rest. `while ((charcter = fgetc(csvFile)) != EOF) {switch (character) {case ',': ++column_count; break; case '\n': ++row_count; break;}}` Don't use `calloc()` id you don't **need** to, it could hide bugs specially involving strings.

Comment: You don't reset `i` and `j` to `0` before the loop that contains the crash so you're writing out of bounds of your allocated arrays.  You need to reset `j` to zero after reading each newline too.  You also don't verify that each field is 9 characters or less, but since you persistently overwrite the same character, that doesn't (yet) matter.  You also need to ensure null terminattion.  You should not test EOF at the end of the `do { … } while (ch != EOF);` loop; you should use a `while ((ch = fgetc(csvFile)) != EOF) { … }` loop.

Comment: You should get into the habit, painful though it be at first, of checking every memory allocation for success, and handling any error appropriately.  Memory allocations do fail; programs that don't check crash, which is not very graceful behaviour.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned value has type `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: when calling `fseek()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: It is best practice, when checking the returned value from a system function, to keep the call to the function immediately followed by the check of the returned value.    Placing the checking of the returned value some number of statements away from the call is very misleading and invites errors when debugging and/or maintaining the code

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when asking a question about some code that does not work correctly, post code that compiles/links cleanly, so we can help you debug the code.   Not posting headers, not posting a main, not posting some example/actual input not posting the actual output, not posting the expected output leaves us wondering if you 1) have read the 'help' 2) really want some debug assistance from us.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) use meaningful variable names.  A variable name should indicate content and/or usage (better to indicate both).  3) use `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give 'magic' numbers meaningful names. (10 is such a 'magic' number)  Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: just as a matter of good coding practice and checking all corner cases:  What happens when the last column in a row is NOT followed by a comma?  What happens when the last row is NOT followed by a newline?

Comment: the posted code has a logic error.  After this line: `fseek(csvFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);`, the code needs to reset 'i' and 'j' to 0 so the actual reading of the file into the array starts at the beginning of the array.

Comment: these lines: `    char** bigArr = calloc(l*c,sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < l*c; i++)
    {
        bigArr[i] = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    }`  are not performing the correct logic.  The first call to `calloc()` should be for the number of rows, The second call to `calloc()` , in a loop,  should allocate the number of columns as pointers on each row.  Then the actual reading of the data should accumulate a complete column, then use something like `strdup()` to place a pointer to the column data into the appropriate location in the array.

Comment: Note: 10 characters will probably not be enough for any text strings in the csv file.  Also, 10 characters is not enough for the text representation of a 'int' nor a 'float' nor a 'double' nor to hold most math calculation formulas.  There is also a problem handling the edge case of when a column is empty I.E. two or more commas in a row with no intervening characters

Comment: the posted code is counting every column in the whole file rather than tracking/finding the row with the most columns

Comment: @user3629249: Strictly, the first (dubious `do { … } while`) loop counts the number of commas in the first line, assuming that there is a newline in the file (it should check for `(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)` to be safe(r)).  The second (equally dubious `do { … } while`) loop counts the number of newlines in the file — and can produce the answer 0.  Both those loops would be better written in idiomatic C as `while` loops: `while ((ch = getc(csvFile)) != EOF && ch != '\n')` and `while ((ch = getc(csvFile)) != EOF)` respectively.

Comment: @user3629249: You're right that the code assumes that the number of columns per line is consistent — a dubious proposition.  As I note in my answer, it also assumes there are no commas within double-quoted fields, nor any newlines with double-quoted fields.  Both those would throw the system off.  Arguably, my code should avoid stepping beyond the end of the columns (so the if a line does have more fields than the first line, it doesn't go scribbling — though most of the time there'd be no harm in that).

Answer (score 2):

The loop that's crashing should be more like:

```
enum { MAX_FIELD_WIDTH = 10 };  // Including null terminator

i = j = 0;
while ((ch = getc(csvFile)) != EOF)
{
    if (ch == ',' || ch == '\n')
    {
        bigArr[i++][j] = '\0';
        j = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (j < MAX_FIELD_WIDTH - 1)
            bigArr[i][j++] = ch;
        // else ignore excess characters
}
```

<sup>*Warning: untested code!*</sup>

Your code is simply creating a linear list of `l * c` field values, which is fine.  You can pick the fields for line `n` by accessing fields `bigArr[n * c]` through `bigArr[n * c + c - 1]` (counting from line 0).

For important variables like `l` and `c`, I use longer names such as `rows` (or `lines`) and `cols`.  Still not long, but more meaningful.  Single character names should be used with limited scope.

Note that this code ignores subtleties of the CSV format such as fields with commas inside double quotes, let alone newlines within double quoted fields.  It also ignores the possibility of varying numbers of fields in the lines.  If the code kept track of line numbers, it would be possible to handle both too many fields (ignoring the extra) and too few fields (creating empty entries for missing fields).  If the code that pre-scans the file was cleverer, it could keep a record of the minimum and maximum number of columns per line as well as the number of lines.  Problems could then be diagnosed too.

With a more complex memory management scheme, it would also be possible to scan the file just once, which has advantages if the file is actually a terminal or pipe, rather than a disk file.  It could also handle arbitrarily long field values instead of restricting them to 10 bytes including the terminal null byte.

---

The code should check that the file could be opened, and close it when it is finished.  The current function interface is:

```
int changeValue(int line, int col, char str[], const char* path)
```

but the first three values are ignored by the code shown.  This is probably because the final code will change one of the values read and then rewrite the file.  Presumably, it would report an error if asked to change a non-existent column or line.  These relatively minor infelicities are probably due to the minimization to make the code resemble an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to read the data and store it in a `char **` pointer, then this is a way to do it

```
int
changeValue(const char *path)
{
    FILE *file;
    size_t column_count;
    size_t row_count;
    int character;
    char **result;
    char *field;
    char large_buffer[100];
    size_t length;
    size_t index;

    file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cant read the file\nPlease open a file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Count Rows and Columns */
    while ((character = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        switch (character)
        {
            case ',':
                ++column_count;
                break;
            case '\n':
                ++row_count;
                break;
        }
    }
    rewind(file);

    result = malloc(row_count * column_count * sizeof(char *));
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return -1; /* Do something to inform the caller */
    }

    length = 0;
    index = 0;
    while ((character = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        switch (character)
        {
            case '\n':
            case ',':
                field = malloc(length + 1);
                if (field != NULL)
                {
                    memcpy(field, large_buffer, length);
                    field[length] = '\0';
                }
                result[index++] = field;

                length = 0;
                break;
            default:
                if (length < sizeof(large_buffer))
                    large_buffer[length++] = character;
                break;
        }
    }
    /* USE THE DATA NOW AND FREE THE POINTERS */
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that:

1. You can count rows and columns to pre-allocate the destination but you can do it in a single loop because you are reading the file one character at a time.
2. You don't need to pre-allocate every pointer in the `char **` array to a fixed size because that doesn't make much sense, you could just use the fixed size to pre-allocate it like this

   ```
   char (*bigArr)[10] = malloc(sizeof(*bigArr));
   ```

   Instead, in the second loop just use a buffer large enough to hold characters until a `','` or `'\n'` is found (*ignore characters if they don't fit, as you would anyway in your code*) and then allocate the pointer and copy the data into it.
3. The actual problem as pointed out in the answer by @[JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37212759/1983495) is that you were not resetting the `j` index properly thus writing after the bounds of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the arr array as it isn't used.

You don't check whether you allocated the bigArr memory ok, nor the smaller arrays in it.

Also you are assigning bigArr[i][j] tp the value of a character, which is not correct - you want to set the array you allocated  in  bigArr[i][j] to it (and will have to handle appending the character within that array since you are reading character by character)

Comment: And someone can click on answer not being useful without giving any reason