# Fseek doesn't do what it should do in C

Tags: c

I made a program to read .csv files. Every new line is after '\n' and every next element is after ','. The whole code is working fine for me. I get place (col and line) and I am trying to change the value in this place by reading the whole file into an array and then search the place with 'i' and trying to fseek that start from 'i' to change there only the needed value, but when I debug I found out that `arr[i]` (the chosen value), is not in the same place as `fseek(csvfile, i, SEEK_SET)`.

Can someone tell me how I `fseek` the file pointer to the 'i' place to change the value?

```
int changeValue(int line, int col, char str[], const char* path)
{
    FILE* csvFile = fopen(path, "r+");
    char arr[VERY_BIG_MEMORY];
    int i = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int q =0;
    if (!csvFile)
    {
        printf("Can't read the file\nPlease open a file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    initarr(arr, VERY_BIG_MEMORY);
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(csvFile);
        arr[i] = (char)ch;
        i++;

    } while (ch != EOF);
    fseek(csvFile,0L, SEEK_SET);
    i = 0;
    q = 1;
    while (q < line)
    {
        ch = arr[i];
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            q++;
        }
        i++;

    }
    q = 1;
    while (q < col)
    {
        ch = arr[i];
        if (ch == ',')
        {
            q++;
        }
        i++;

    }
    q = 0;
    fseek(csvFile,i,SEEK_SET );
    //ch = arr[i];
    //ch = fgetc(csvFile);
    /*while (str[q])
    {
        fputc(str[q], csvFile);
        q++;
    }*/
    fclose(csvFile);
}
```

Comment: Not a direct response to your problem but why not use fgets? Or even fread for your buffer fill?

Comment: You probably need to open the file in binary mode, by adding `b` to the second argument.

Comment: Related to, but different from, another question recent on 'handling CSV files'.  …  It seems it was another user ID: [Some code of reading CSV file crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212191/some-code-of-reading-csv-file-crashed).  There's a strong family resemblance between the code; maybe same homework assignment and same hints from the teacher.

Comment: Note that if the replacement field is a different length from the data in the source file, you'll have to do some tweaking of the copying.  If you're on Windows, the input may be counting `\r\n` line endings as one character, but the `fseek()` is not.  With text files, you can seek to previously encountered locations, but not necessarily to arbitrary other locations.  So, your `fseek(csvFile, i, SEEK_SET)` is certainly not guaranteed to work on Windows platforms.

Comment: If you open the file in binary mode then seek is reliable. Just expect/handle `\r\n` line endings on windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, `VERY_BIG_MEMORY`. I hope that is not a teacher hint. Anything "very big" definitely should not be a local variable.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the (probably #define) declaration of the value: `VERY_BIG_MEMORY`.  If `VERY_BIG_MEMORY` is a #define, then no need to pass it as a parameter to some local function.